# Floating point comparison with zero at end

Tags: javascript

Something that's always puzzled me is comparing floating point values in JS with zeros at end.

A simple use case would be comparing version numbers.

I want to check if the current version is less than something like 6.10.

But when doing below, it doesn't work because `parseFloat` removes the zero from 6.10, effectively making it 6.1 and invalidating the comparison.

```
var currentVersion = '6.10'
if(parseFloat(currentVersion) > parseFloat('6.9')) {
  // do something
}
```

The only other way, sans node-module, I've seen it done is to split the values on ".", and compare them individually.

Would love an easier solution that would work in the browser.

**EDIT** As pointed out, I was thinking of version numbers as floating point values when I shouldn't have. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: And when you have `1.25.12.23` ? You should parse it

Comment: I may fail at maths but to me 6.9 > 6.10... As @dystroy said, you should parse each value and compare them as integers.

Comment: Your version numbers are not floating point numbers - if they were, `6.9` would read `6.09`.

Comment: you are all correct. i appreciate the input.